# Get number of satellites using fused location

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

Is there a way to get number of satellites using fused location?

I tried using this

```
location.getExtras().getInt("satellites")
```

but it didn't work

Then I tried using `GpsStatus` but I can't use it cause I am not using the `LocationManager`.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, Fused Location does not have the sattelites information when you `Location.getExtras()`. You would basically get a `NullPointerException`.

As you said, `GpsStatus` is the only way to do it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I tried that but it said I needed 50 reputation which I did not have.

Comment: But posting a comment as an answer is no alternative

Comment: As a matter of fact, I fail to see why this does not answer the question. It was not a critique or clarification request.

The OP asked if it was possible to get the number of satellites using Fused Location and it is not, therefore I answered so. 

I also confirmed exactly his second question "GpsStatus is the only way to do it".

Comment: Maybe it is an answer, but I would recommend posting a comment instead, and look at your downvotes to see what the community thinks

Comment: I don't judge the validity of my response based on "what the community thinks". If you cannot provide a valid reasoning why my response is not a valid answer, then your argument remains invalid.